# How to prohibit creating custom view by xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I force a custom view to be created dynamically?

I tried removing construct with attributeset, but it didn't make compile-time errors.

Comment: How about throwing an exception in that constructor?

Comment: @malrok44 wouldn't an exception always get thrown, then? Or you'd always catch it in the code?

Comment: @malrok44 I want to prohibit running.

Comment: In other words, I want to make the build failed.

Comment: Please explain why you want this behavior. The XML will always allow you to place the custom view in it. You can throw an exception, but it's your code, so you should know yourself not to put that view in the XML

Comment: @cricket_007 I know it behavior now, but other people may not, and I can make a mistake. So I want to make it hard to use incorrectly.

Comment: Do you plan on sharing your code with many people? Can't you just tell them not to put that view in the XML?

Comment: @cricket_007 I can rely on documentations, but I want to prohibit incorrect behavior in compile-time if I can.

Comment: I feel like this is only possible at runtime, not compile time

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make the build failed

That's not possible, sorry. The build tools do not know what sort of inflation mechanism will be used to convert a layout XML resource into Java objects. Hence, the build tools do not know what is and is not a valid `View` subclass for the purposes of that inflation.

Comment: Then, is there an annatation that indicates "not to use it in xml"?

Comment: @GimunEom: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: So an exception being thrown in the constructor would or wouldn't crash the app at view inflation unless caught appropriately?

Comment: @cricket_007: It would crash the app at *runtime*. The OP wishes to fail the build, which is a compile-time act. Crashing at runtime is eminently possible. IMHO, the right answer is "allow the `View` to be put in a layout resource", at which point this whole issue falls away.